# My new computer won't turn on, GPU just blinks

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, gpu

Just assembled my first computer and when I try to turn it on the gpu just blinks a red light for a second on the GIGABYTE led display and nothing happens.

My psu has a voltage selector and I'm almost certain that I chose the correct one (my house has 110v and the selector is at 115v).

I double checked the case buttons connectors and they are in their places .

I also have a thermaltake fan controller connected directly to the psu and it does not turn on either.

Here is a photo of the computer (sorry for the bad cable management, this is my first computer assembled):
[image: https://s30.postimg.org/k0v4zzixt/P_20161227_134051_2.jpg]

Here is the motherboard without the gpu and second push fan on radiator:
[image: https://s28.postimg.org/k8qoirzzh/P_20161227_163933_1.jpg]

The ATX cable is connected to the motherboard behind the radiator in the top left of the image.

My computer specs:

- Motherboard ASUS B150M-C/BR
- Gigabyte GEForce GTX 1060 windforce
- Intel core i5 6600k
- PSU Xigmatek Calibre 600w
- Case corsair carbide spec-03
- Corsair hydro cooler h55
- SSD 500GB and 2TB + 160GB HDD
- 8GB RAM Kingston DDR4

PS: I tried to turn it on without the PCI-E cable connected to the GPU and it still blinks red and turn off
PS2: Just made the paper clip test on the psu and it doesn't start the fan. It may be the source of the problem, but why my GPU flashed red before?

I'm open to suggestions and I can perform tests.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT: The solution was reinserting all motherboard psu connectors and RAM and forcing them a little more inside.
Thanks for everyone that helped!**

Comment: Check all the cables, and make sure they are plugged in fully. Check if the GPU is seated all the way in the slot. I have a feeling the PSU either may not be supplying enough power for some reason or its cables are not plugged in correctly.

Comment: Just checked it, pressed the gpu and motherboard cables and nothing happened

Comment: I have this feeling either, but my psu is 600w 80 plus white. I think that's enough power, right?

Comment: Does the computer turn on if you remove everything except for the motherboard, CPU (with heat sink and fan), power supply, and 1 stick of RAM?

Comment: should be enough

Comment: I think I *might* see a CPU power cord running from the PSU to the cpu power connector, but check to ensure it is not being crushed under the cooler and is still connected properly.

Comment: I tried removing everything as Hydraxan stated, but nothing happened. Here's the photo https://s28.postimg.org/k8qoirzzh/P_20161227_163933_1.jpg

Comment: @Yorik, the cable looks fine and well placed here. If you need a closer photo I can take it.

Comment: Just made the paper clip test on the psu and it doesn't start the fan

Comment: With the GPU not installed, clear the CMOS (see your manual). Then power it on, and wait. It is possible the system is doube-posting or doing {magic} ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_boot ) should not take long, but its possible you are interrupting some process.

Comment: @Yorik I can't turn the PC on to clear the CMOS, the problem looks like to happen before it is loaded. As stated by the paper clip test, it looks like my psu is the source of the problem, but I'm confused by the gpu flashing red and turning off.

Comment: remove the battery. I do not think the GPU has any diagnostic lights, just "vanity lights"

Comment: @Yorik removed the battery, reconnected the ATX and motherboard power cables and it didn't worked either. The computer showed no sign of turning on even after 1 minute wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to remove all cpu connectors from the PSU and the RAM and reinsert them all as Andrew Li suggested in the comments. To be sure that they were all connected, I waited for a click sound.

Thanks for everyone that helped.

Answer (score 0):

## 2020 experience ..

I have an (excellent) iBuyPower with an ASUS graphics card, about a yr old.

I got exactly this strange problem, the gpu would blink at me.

In short, I

- simply reseated the graphics card
- I happened to plugged in an M2 recently. I took it out

all worked perfectly again.

Conceivably, when fiddling around plugging in the M2 card the other day (it's right next to the GPU card) I may have slightly bumped something. In any event, thank goodness, reseating everything worked.